# Text not changing using DOM. Error message says "cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know this is a very simple problem, and it probably is already answered, but no answers work.

So, when I click the seven button, it is supposed to change the heading to 7. I am not done with my program yet, so none of the other buttons work. It returns the error message on the chrome console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null. Thanks in advance! Here is my code:

```js
var num2;
var answer;
var num1;
function whenNumPressed(inumber){
document.getElementById(output).innerHTML = inumber;

}
```

```css
#center{
 text-align: center;
 font-family: Comic Sans MS;
 font-size: 50px;
 color:black;
}
#outputButton{
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  font-size:50px;
  text-size:100;
}
*{
  text-align:center;
  color:red;
  font-family: Comic Sans MS;
}
#input{
  width:167px;
  font-size:30px;
  height:100px;
}
#output{
  border-style: solid;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right:20px;
  border-color:blue;
  font-size:60px;
}
#calc{
  border-style:solid;
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-right:300px;
  border-width:10px;
  border-radius:50px;
  border-color:green;
}
#specialinput{
  width:334px;
  font-size:30px;
  height:100px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="calc">
<h1 id="center">Calculator</h1>
<h1 id="output">Answer</h1>
<br>
<button id="input" onclick="whenNumPressed('7')">7</button>
<button id="input">8</button>
<button id="input">9</button>
<button id="input">+</button>

<br>
<button id="input">4</button>
<button id="input">5</button>
<button id="input">6</button>
<button id="input">-</button>
<br>
<button id="input">1</button>
<button id="input">2</button>
<button id="input">3</button>
<button id="input">X</button>
<br>
<button id="input">AC</button>
<button id="input">0</button>
<button id="input">=</button>
<button id="input">÷</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("output")` ... etc

Comment: `document.getElementById(output)` You never defined a variable named `output`.

Comment: do i have to dont i just have to put the id

Comment: Multiple elements with id *input* is not going to work, id's are supposed to be unique. And IDs are strings, so `document.getElementById('output')`. But that's the h1 element, maybe you want `document.getElementById('input'+inumber)`.

Comment: Wait no, I put output, not input.

Comment: Consider using *input* elements instead: `<input type="button" value="8" onclick="alert(this.value)">` because they really are inputs, not buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you are mentioning any strings you have to keep it in quotations otherwise it will take it as variable name.

So do this minor change in your code and check.

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = inumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the quotes:

`document.getElementById(output)` should be `document.getElementById('output')`

```js
var num2;
var answer;
var num1;
function whenNumPressed(inumber){
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = inumber;

}
```

```css
#center{
 text-align: center;
 font-family: Comic Sans MS;
 font-size: 50px;
 color:black;
}
#outputButton{
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  font-size:50px;
  text-size:100;
}
*{
  text-align:center;
  color:red;
  font-family: Comic Sans MS;
}
#input{
  width:167px;
  font-size:30px;
  height:100px;
}
#output{
  border-style: solid;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right:20px;
  border-color:blue;
  font-size:60px;
}
#calc{
  border-style:solid;
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-right:300px;
  border-width:10px;
  border-radius:50px;
  border-color:green;
}
#specialinput{
  width:334px;
  font-size:30px;
  height:100px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="calc">
<h1 id="center">Calculator</h1>
<h1 id="output">Answer</h1>
<br>
<button id="input" onclick="whenNumPressed('7')">7</button>
<button id="input">8</button>
<button id="input">9</button>
<button id="input">+</button>

<br>
<button id="input">4</button>
<button id="input">5</button>
<button id="input">6</button>
<button id="input">-</button>
<br>
<button id="input">1</button>
<button id="input">2</button>
<button id="input">3</button>
<button id="input">X</button>
<br>
<button id="input">AC</button>
<button id="input">0</button>
<button id="input">=</button>
<button id="input">÷</button>
</div>
```